# how to create correct search when i use slug django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

> edit , with this code it will work fine

if you want create search from multiple models with slug you must take this code and edit it with your info

in models.py add these lines in up page :

```
from django.db.models import Q

class SearchManager(models.Manager):
    def search(self, query=None):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        if query is not None:
            or_lookup = (Q(name__icontains=query) | #replace name with field that you want grab data from it
                         Q(app_contect__icontains=query)| #replace app_contect with field that you want grab data from it
                         Q(slug__icontains=query) #replace slug with slug name feild
                        )
            qs = qs.filter(or_lookup).distinct() # distinct() is often necessary with Q lookups
        return qs
        
        
class YourMoels(models.Model):
    objects = SearchManager() # add this line in every models you want add them to search
```

in views.py (edit the templete and models name) :

```
#search

class SearchView(ListView):
    template_name = 'website_primary_html_pages/search.html'
    paginate_by = 2
    count = 0

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['count'] = self.count or 0
        context['query'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        request = self.request
        query = request.GET.get('q', None)

        if query is not None:
            android_results        = Android.objects.search(query)
            linux_results      = Linux.objects.search(query)
            tech_results     = Tech.objects.search(query)
            mobile_results     = Mobile.objects.search(query)
            windows_results     = Windows.objects.search(query)

            # combine querysets
            queryset_chain = chain(
                    android_results,
                    linux_results,
                    tech_results,
                    mobile_results,
                    windows_results
            )


            qs = sorted(queryset_chain,
                        key=lambda instance: instance.pk,
                        reverse=True)
            self.count = len(qs) # since qs is actually a list
            return qs

        return Android.objects.none() # just an empty queryset as default
```

in search.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load templatetag %} # add this line in up page

        <h3 class='text-center' id="" style="color:#7952b3;font-size:35px">{{ count }} {{ query }}</h3><br>

  {% for object in page_obj %}
       {% with object|class_name as klass %}

         {% if klass == 'Mobile' %}
         <div class="card-deck">
           <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 800px;">
             <div class="row no-gutters">
               <div class="col-md-4">
       <!-- edit Mobile to your page path in url-->   <a href='Mobile/{{ object.slug }}'><img style="height:100%;width:100%;border-radius:6.5px;" src="{{ object.get_image }}" class="rounded float-right" alt="..."></a>
               </div>

               <div class="col-md-8">
                 <div class="card-body">
       <!-- edit Mobile to your page path in url-->  <a href='Mobile/{{ object.slug }}'> <h5 class="card-title" id="primary_site_pages_app_name_control"> <b>{{ object.name }}</b></h5></a>
                   <p class="card-text" id="font_control_for_all_pages">{{ object.app_contect|truncatechars_html:153|safe}}</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="card-footer">
                  <small class="text-muted" id="date_post_control">{{ object.post_date}}</small>
                  <small class="firstsmall"><a class="bg-orange" href="{% url 'mobile' %}" id="tag_name_control">هواتف</a></small>
                </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           </div>
           <hr>

         {% elif klass == 'Linux' %}
         <div class="card-deck">
           <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 800px;">
             <div class="row no-gutters">
               <div class="col-md-4">
          <!-- edit Linux to your page path in url-->  <a href='Linux/{{ object.slug }}'><img style="height:100%;width:100%;border-radius:6.5px;" src="{{ object.get_image }}" class="rounded float-right" alt="..."></a>
               </div>

               <div class="col-md-8">
                 <div class="card-body">
           <!-- edit Linux to your page path in url-->  <a href='Linux/{{ object.slug }}'> <h5 class="card-title" id="primary_site_pages_app_name_control"> <b>{{ object.name }}</b></h5></a>
                   <p class="card-text" id="font_control_for_all_pages">{{ object.app_contect|truncatechars_html:153|safe}}</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="card-footer">
                  <small class="text-muted" id="date_post_control">{{ object.post_date}}</small>
                  <small class="firstsmall"><a class="bg-orange" href="{% url 'linux' %}" id="tag_name_control">لينكس</a></small>
                </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           </div>
           <hr>

        <!-- add more model like this way in above -->

      {% else %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endwith %}
{% empty %}

   <div class='row'>
       <div class='col-12 col-md-6 mx-auto my-5 py-5'>
       <form method='GET' class='' action="{% url 'search' %}">

           <div class="input-group form-group-no-border mx-auto" style="margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 32px;">
               <span class="input-group-addon cfe-nav" style='color:#000'>
                   <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
               </span>
               <input type="text" name="q" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Press enter to search" class="form-control cfe-nav mt-0 py-3" placeholder="Search..." value="" style="" data-original-title="" title="" autofocus="autofocus">
           </div>

       </form>

       </div>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
{% if is_paginated %}

  {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
    <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page=1{{ page_obj.paginator.start_index }}{% for k,v in request.GET.items %}{% if k != 'page' %}&{{ k }}={{ v }}{% endif %}{%endfor%}">First</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}{% for k,v in request.GET.items %}{% if k != 'page' %}&{{ k }}={{ v }}{% endif %}{%endfor%}">Previous</a>
  {% endif %}

  {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
    {% if page_obj.number == num %}
      <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}{% for k,v in request.GET.items %}{% if k != 'page' %}&{{ k }}={{ v }}{% endif %}{%endfor%}">{{ num }}</a>
    {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
      <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}{% for k,v in request.GET.items %}{% if k != 'page' %}&{{ k }}={{ v }}{% endif %}{%endfor%}">{{ num }}</a>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

  {% if page_obj.has_next %}
    <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}{% for k,v in request.GET.items %}{% if k != 'page' %}&{{ k }}={{ v }}{% endif %}{%endfor%}">Next</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}{% for k,v in request.GET.items %}{% if k != 'page' %}&{{ k }}={{ v }}{% endif %}{%endfor%}">Last</a>
  {% endif %}

{% endif %}
```

in urls.py :

```
from blog_app.views import SearchView
urlpatterns = [
    path('Search', SearchView.as_view(), name='search'),
]
```

and don't forget add templatetag folder then create  `templatetag.py` and `__init__.py` inside templatetag folder

- keep `__init__.py` empty then open `templatetag.py` and edit it with this lines :

  ```
  # search.templatetags.class_name.py
  from django import template

  register = template.Library()

  @register.filter()
  def class_name(value):
      return value.__class__.__name__
  ```

in settings.py add this new line :

```
    TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        'libraries':{ #new line
            'templatetag': 'blog_app.templatetags.templatetag', #new line

            }
        },
    },
]
```

for any questions please write comment below and i will help you !

Answer (score 0):

The slug is just a string, to link to it from the template use the name you've given the link:

```
href="{% url '<appname>:android_posts' slug=result.slug %}"
```

Comment: thanks , and when i have more than one model what should i do ?

Comment: because search for all models

Comment: Either reverse the URL link in the view and pass as text or have an {% if %} statement in the template. Or harmonise your URLs and have the view redirect, though that's a bit messy maybe.

Comment: how to make any of these solution can you help with that and i will be thankful

Comment: I suggest reading the rather excellent docs :) Here's the link for `if` in the templates for example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#if

Comment: My gut feeling though is your DB design is all wrong and that multiple models is not the way to go ... but that's a much bigger topic!

Comment: i have edit my code and work fine .. anyone who see this question you will find the correct way

Comment: Happy to hear it :) do take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)